# How to make programmatically add horizontal and vertical scollview in android

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to such type horizontal and vertical scroll view dynamically add in android. but i have not added title. if any one idea how to add title on each top of the horizontal view. Here first is different and others are same.

[image]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should first take a `ListView` and then add items inside it using `HorizontalScrollView`. Use any adapter to set items inside `ListView`. This way you can scroll vertically (`ListView`) and horizontally also.

Reference :

- [Horizontal-Vertical scrollable view](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/01/horizontal-vertical-scrollable-view.html)
- [Horizontal and Vertical Scrolling in Android](https://androiddesk.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical">

<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="320px" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linlay" android:layout_width="320px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:background="#000000"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```